# Excel - basic copy-paste between sheets macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a basic merge of data from 2 sheets where the first part (username) changes, but the second part is say, a preset list of 120 items.  ie, combine:

```
sheet1:USERLIST
albert
benny
cedric
dorothy
....
```

with

```
sheet2:ITEMLIST
item1
item2
item3
....
item120
```

so the final output on another sheet (in separate cells) is

```
sheet3
albert item1
albert item2
....
albert item120
benny item1
benny item2
....
benny item120
cedric item1
cedric item2
....
cedric item120
```

and so on.  I know this is a pretty basic question but I havent found the answer thus far.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simply done in a two level `For...Next`.

Suppose you have:

- [Sheet1]:

```
    USER_LIST
    A
    B
    C
```

- [Sheet2]:

```
    ITEM_LIST
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

- [Sheet3]:

```
    RESULT_LIST
```

With this sub:

```vb
Private Sub Whatever_name_you_like()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = 2 To Worksheets(1).Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To Worksheets(2).Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets(3).Cells(Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value & Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

When run, [Sheet3] will results in:

```
RESULT_LIST
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked out great for me!  Although, what is the syntax for getting the contents of [sheet1] and [sheet2] in separate cells in [sheet3] rather than concatenating them?

Comment: @user2314646 `Worksheets(n).Cells(row,col).Value` will get the value of cell(row,col) in worksheet n, e.g. `Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value` will get cell `A1` in sheet 1.

Answer (score 1):

can you not just do this with a formula in the target range:

```
=Sheet1!A:A&Sheet2!A:A
```

just copy that formula in all your target cells.

This avoids using VBA and a loop, and takes advantage of Excels built-in functionality so no need to kick off VBA code

Comment: Are you sure? Because I tested on 2003 and with `ABC` in S1 and `12345` in S2 I got `A1 B2 C3` in S3, not `A1...A5 B1...B5` etc..

Comment: are you might need an array formula for that, I'll take a look